# My HyperV Virtual Server stops with critical error

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I on microsoft hyper v create a server, i installing on it linux debian, but while installation this server stopped with critical error and if I start it, he stops after approximaly 1 minute.

How to debug it?
Where i can find information about this critical error because in a events viewer I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Hyper-V (RTM or R2), do you have all the latest hotfixes installed?

I assume the VM is server that is experiencing the critical error?

Debian isn't supported on Hyper-V (see supported guest list - http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-supported-guest-os.aspx).. saying that people have successfully got this up and running (see http://wiki.debian.org/WindowsServerHyperV)

I suggest checking that your VM has only one v.CPU and you are using the legacy network adapter.

Good luck, please post your results, I am interested to see if you can get it working.

Comment: @commandbreak: Result is: diskspace don't most carry all disk space. (Enough space on disk)

Answer (score 0):

I need more info (like what system is on your virtual server). Assuming that is not linux -

1. Enable bootlog at startup by going to safe mode with F8
2. Mount / install the disk somewhere else and analyse the log in %SystemRoot%\Ntbtlog.txt